# Multi handle slider with data bind using mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

How to create Multi handle slider using Kendo Ui OR jQuery that shows percentage data bind using MVC/SignalR as below:

[image]

Here if i change(slide) "Internet" handle from 39% to 20%, the "eMail" handle should be changed from 13% to 32%.

How can i achieve this using data bind to/from the slider from MVC/SignalR?

Comment: As far as I know, Kendo's slider control doesn't support multiple sliders / values. You would have to make your own control.

Comment: How to achieve this using jQuery & SignalR? Is any jQuery widget is available that can be customize?

Comment: I don't know any. Google is your friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieve this by customizing the free javascript plugin from http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/ . I have used Multi range slider plug in and customize it as per the need.